# overloading stream manipulator operator

Tags: stream, overloading, std, ostream, manipulators

Hi I am trying to overload the operator<< to hook into

```
stream << std::endl;
```

to avoid '\n' to be appended if I don't need output.
I alredy overloaded:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& (*pf)(std::ostream&))
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ios& (*pf)(std::ios&))
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ios_base& (*pf)(std::ios_base&))
```

But the call ends always at basic_ostream

```
_Myt& __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL operator<<(_Myt& (__cdecl *_Pfn)(_Myt&))
{// call basic_ostream manipulator
    _DEBUG_POINTER(_Pfn);
    return ((*_Pfn)(*this));
}
```

Comment: With other manipulators like std::hex its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself

Problem was that other overloaded operators returned std::ostream& so the overloaded function could not be called.